# Growth Factor in an Exponential Word Problem

Tags: exponential-function

I was doing an exponential function word problem

Question:

Assume that the population of the United States is increasing exponentially with time. The 1970 census showed that the population was about 203 million. The 1980 census showed that the population had grown to about 226 million.

By what factor did the population increase from 1970 to 1980?

Here is what I did:[image]

I assumed that when it was asking for the "factor" is what asking for the growth factor, which in this case is 1.0107..... However, the book says it is 1.1133005.

I was wondering if anyone knew what went wrong.

Thank you

Comment: They haven't gotten to the exponential part yet. $226/203\approx1.11$

Comment: How do you know they are not tlaking about exponential yet in this question?

Comment: Because the word "factor" has nothing to do with exponentials.

Comment: Please type with MathJax there. Don't give us the handwritten *notes*!